# Accessing IBOutlet from within another class's delegate

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm having trouble accessing an IBOutlet. In Class A I have a scrollview who's delegate is set as Class B.

Class A Header

```
@property(nonatomic, strong) ClassB *B;
```

Class A Implementation

```
self.B = [[ClassB alloc] init];

[_scrollview setDelegate:self.B];
```

Now the scrollview calls the scrollViewDidScroll did scroll correctly in ClassB

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
```

But I can't access any IBOutlets declared in ClassB from the scrollViewDidScroll. They just return nil.

Comment: How are you trying to access the IBOutlets?

Comment: `self.A = [[ClassB alloc] init];` what?  I think `A` should be `B`?

Answer (score 0):

It is because you have declared that property as Class A in your header. Change below line in ClassA.h

```
@property(nonatomic, strong) ClassA *A;
```

with this line.

```
@property(nonatomic, strong) ClassB *A;
```

Answer (score 0):

You are creating your delegate object(B) in class A. This will work but probably you wont get the outlets. Since the delegate and the object to which you connected the outlets will be two different instance of thee classB. So what you have to do is set the delegate from the classA (as self) before going to classB.

Answer (score 0):

To access Outlets you need load your's ClassB from NIB.

See: 
[- (NSArray *)loadNibNamed:(NSString *)name owner:(id)owner options:(NSDictionary *)options](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/NSBundle_UIKitAdditions/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007485-CH1-SW5)